# Android: Slowing down a recursive Algorithm

Tags: android, recursion

I am currently working on a game. It's a simple one that doesn't require, and thus does not use, a framework of any kind. Right now the code works fine concerning the movement and collision between objects; however, I believe my Recursive fuction is too 'fast' and only shows the last movement of the objects instead of showing the steps they take.

In short:
The levels are bordered, and inside of these borders are movable objects which slide in 4 directions, depending on your 'fling' motion. But instead of the objects visibly sliding, they 'teleport' to their final destination.

This is my function:

```
public void MoveObjects(){
    boolean allCollided = true;
    int moveSpeed = 8;

    //Up and Left movement              
    if(upMotion || leftMotion){
        for(int i = 0; i < movables.size(); i++){
            int oldX = movables.get(i).position.x;
            int oldY = movables.get(i).position.y;
            int newX = 0;
            int newY = 0;

            if(leftMotion)
                newX = oldX-moveSpeed;
            if(upMotion)
                newY = oldY-moveSpeed;

            //Make sure neither newX or newY is 0
            if(newX == 0)
                newX = oldX;
            if(newY == 0)
                newY = oldY;

            movables.get(i).Position(newX, newY);

            for(GameObject go : level){
                if(movables.get(i).Collision(go) && go.spriteID != R.drawable.nothing){
                    if(leftMotion)
                        newX=oldX;
                    if(upMotion)
                        newY=oldY;

                    movables.get(i).collided = true;
                }
            }
            for(GameObject go : movables){
                if(movables.get(i).Collision(go) && go.spriteID != R.drawable.nothing && go != movables.get(i)){
                    if(leftMotion)
                        newX=oldX;
                    if(upMotion)
                        newY=oldY;

                    movables.get(i).collided = true;
                }
            }

            movables.get(i).Position(newX, newY);
        }
    }
    //Down and Right movement
    if(downMotion || rightMotion){
        for(int i = movables.size()-1; i > -1 ; i--){
            int oldX = movables.get(i).position.x;
            int oldY = movables.get(i).position.y;
            int newX = 0;
            int newY = 0;

            if(rightMotion)
                newX = oldX+moveSpeed;
            if(downMotion)
                newY = oldY+moveSpeed;

            //Make sure neither newX or newY is 0
            if(newX == 0)
                newX = oldX;
            if(newY == 0)
                newY = oldY;

            movables.get(i).Position(newX, newY);

            for(GameObject go : level){
                if(movables.get(i).Collision(go) && go.spriteID != R.drawable.nothing){
                    if(rightMotion)
                        newX=oldX;
                    if(downMotion)
                        newY=oldY;

                    movables.get(i).collided = true;
                }
            }
            for(GameObject go : movables){
                if(movables.get(i).Collision(go) && go.spriteID != R.drawable.nothing && go != movables.get(i)){
                    if(rightMotion)
                        newX=oldX;
                    if(downMotion)
                        newY=oldY;

                    movables.get(i).collided = true;
                }
            }

            movables.get(i).Position(newX, newY);
        }
    }

    //Check all objects for collision
    for(int i = 0; i < movables.size(); i++){
        if(!movables.get(i).collided)
            allCollided = false;
    }

    checkShapes();
    updateDraw();

    if(!allCollided)
        MoveObjects();
}
```

I am aware of the oddities in my code, and I need to clean it up at some point, but here's a description:

-Depending on the fling-direction, a different loop is used to accurately calculate collisions

-movables is a 'GameObject' Vector of all movable objects in the current level

-After the initial collision checks, another for-loop (I can convert this to a for-each loop, I know) is used to see if there are any uncollided objects present.

-Based on this final loop, the 'allCollided' boolean is set to false.

-The game then checks which matching objects have collided and removes them from the screen, and then the screen is updated accordingly.

-Close with a final 'if'-statement to see if the 'MoveObjects()' function needs to be called again (Recursively)

So now for the question:
How do I manually slow down this loop, and is it wise to do so? Is there perhaps a different solution for this matter? **Thread.sleep()** does not work, and it is also unwise, but it was worth a shot.

Comment: Not quite the issue here. I tested it without recursion, and every call for 'MoveObjects()' is a single step. So regardless of me placing it in either loop (which slows the function down significantly) or placing it at the end, there should only be one step per call, and not the entire 'road', so to speak. I will continue to look at the issue and hope I'll be able to resolve it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue by placing my MoveObjects() function inside a CountDownTimer; this way, the MoveObjects() function ánd the updateDraw() method are called once every tick, instead of recursively in a single frame.